# Get list of relations for an entity in typeORM?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am using repository pattern with typeORM. For an entity defined below like this

```
@Entity()
export class Apple extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  createdDate: Date;

  @ManyToOne((type) => xyz, (xyz) => xyz.fruit)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'fruit' })
  fruit: Fruit;

  @ManyToOne((type) => ABC, (abc) => abc.juice)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'juice' })
  juice: Juice;
 
}
```

Is there a way to get a list of all relations i.e. an array like format ['fruit','juice']

Comment: yes there is a way! just read here https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations

Comment: Hey! I did read the text provided under the link. It does not specify anywhere how to get relations by accessing the entity. For example, for entity User there should be a way to get all realtions, User.getAllRelations(). Or some other way to achieve these results

Comment: What you want is actually very complicated. I can't even imagine where you are going to use that and how. So why don't you add some more codes and the other 2 missing models so that I could help you to write the functionality you need

Comment: I think those relations have been written wrongly. Add the other 2

Comment: @Nux Thanks for your response.
My use case it to maintain somewhere the relations available on an entity. This will allow me to create a method which returns these relations on the entity. This said method will help in other places of code to "choose and pick" the relations required from the returned array of relations, thus making sure that I don't always use all the relations for queries such as findById etc

Comment: @nux Actually this is just an example. I understand that the other 2 entities must also implement the relation. But the Idea is to get the list of relations on 1 particular entity at a time. 
Such as Apple.getAllRelations()

there are a few questions that ask for the same functionality actually
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690445/get-relations-from-class-typeorm

Comment: One can also think of this as a way to maintain a repository of relations per entity inside a app so that one doesn't need to hardcode this list anywhere and optimise the queries by passing only the required relations from this repo (array of relations returned by Entity.getAllRelations())

Comment: have you tried using ```eager:true```?

Answer (score 2):

This will list you the propery names.

```
entityManager.getRepository(Apple)
      .metadata
      .relations
      .filter(relation => relation.isManyToOne)
      .map(relation => relation.propertyName)
```

If you want the column names, you can use:

```
entityManager.getRepository(Apple)
      .metadata
      .relations
      .filter(relation => relation.isManyToOne)
      .map(relation => relation.joinColumns.map(column => column.databaseName))
```

Mind that due to multi-column keys, each property may have multiple columns.